# dynamic date in R to insert in url

Tags: r

I’m working in Power BI and am using R-script to insert a dynamic date in a URL.

The URL in question is as following

```
Tests <- read.csv(file=paste0("https://www,testtest/getCsv?startdate_Day=1&startdate_Month=01&startdate_Year=2016"), header=TRUE, sep=";")
```

My problem is that the day month and year value has to always be the current date

I have tried or example

```
Year<-Sys.Date() format(Year, format="%Y")

Month<-Sys.Date() format(Month, format="%m")

Day<-Sys.Date() format(Day, format="%d")

<- read.csv(file=paste0("read.csv(file=paste0("https://www,testtest/getCsv??startdate_Day=", Day,"&startdate_Month=", Month,"&startdate_Year=", Year"), header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

But then I get the following error:

> startdate_Day=2016-08-12&startdate_Month=2016-08-12&startdate_Year=2016-08-12

My question is how I fill Startdate_Day, Startdate_Month and Startdate_Year automatically with the current Day, Month and Year?

Comment: you mean like this? `format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")`   and in the last line is quite messed up... check the quotation marks

Comment: you mean the link `https://www.testtest` ? Point not Comma ?

Answer (score 0):

If that's the exact code you're running, then you're having a few problems:

1. As noted, you have a comma in your url (`www.test`), do you mean to?
2. Your calls to `Sys.Date()` and `format` aren't written properly.

Try this:

```
# Get the date parts we need
Year <-format(Sys.Date(), format="%Y")
Month <- format(Sys.Date(), format="%m")
Day <- format(Sys.Date(), format="%d")

# Create the file string
file_string <- paste0("https://www.testtest/getCsv??startdate_Day=", Day,"&startdate_Month=", Month,"&startdate_Year=", Year)

# Run read.csv
EnergyStockVolumeData  <- read.csv(file_string, header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

Comment: He thansk for the solution it works great at first try now i can go with fine tuning it